# Question on hold etiquette

Tags: discussion, on-hold-questions

Hello folks: is there a polite way to draw attention of moderators that a question should not be on hold? I do not want to appeal to a decision of keeping a question on hold but my impression is that the moderators may have forgotten to take a look at it after the initial decision because my comment on it did not received any reply.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788766/quadratic-equations-factoring-into-linear-factors/788825#788825

Comment: This is not handled by the moderators, but by high-reputation users. There is a dedicated thread for [requesting reopen votes](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-votes). [For what it's worth, I think the question should be on-hold in its current state - it wasn't closed as 'unclear,' but as 'missing context or details'.]

Comment: @T.Bongers: thanks I will try to edit it them